# Have forked child process not stop when parent stops NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have something that creates a child process that has a setTimeout in it. I pass a number through for the setTimeout, but the problem is that when the parent exits, the child dies. I need the child to live, even if the parent dies. How would I do that?

Parent file (mute.js)

```js
const muteTiming = fork("timeHandler/timeMute.js");
...
muteTiming.send(mutedTime)
muteTiming.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg === "All done!"){
    member.roles.remove(mutedRole);
  }
 });
```

Child Process (timeMute.js)

```js
process.on("message", (msg) => {
  let mutedTime = msg;
  try {
    console.log("Started mute on child!");
    let checkDone = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      process.send("All done!");
      checkDone = true;
      console.log("Done!");
    }, mutedTime);
    while (checkDone === false) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Not done yet...");
      }, 5000);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Uh Oh! The child spit out an error. Here it is! ${error}`);
  }
});
```

I tried

```js
    while (checkDone === false) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Not done yet...");
      }, 5000);
    }
```

but that doesn't keep it alive. Anything I should do?

Also, I've tried spawn. It won't work for what I need to do. At least as far as I know. I need to just pass something to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to handle child processes. Using [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) creates a new process in which one can [send](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) messages. This link is a good primer in that:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/

If using Windows, pay attention to [process.kill](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal) as it handles signals differently.

Comment: I've tried spawn, but it doesn't do what I need to do. I need to be able to send a parameter to the child process, but as far as I know, I can't do that with spawn.

Comment: Please read the linked article. One can [send](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) messages to a spawned process.